# Is it possible to setup password expirey for gnome display manager during login?

Tags: linux, passwords, login, gnome

I want to setup password expirey which warns 3 days before hand and forces user to change password after 30 days. Is this possible for gnome display manager? I want to make it so that it changes the password for both sudo and login and it should automatically change password for seahorse to the current one as well so that it automatically unlocks after login. Is this something possible without writing a script or something?

Comment: How about not forcing password expiry - this has been against recommendations by most security organisations for about a decade. See UK gov - https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/collection/passwords/updating-your-approach - & US gov - https://www.ftc.gov/policy/advocacy-research/tech-at-ftc/2016/03/time-rethink-mandatory-password-changes - for two of the most prominent advisories, or google "password expiration no longer recommended"

Comment: Yes, I am aware and I know but that is not going to stop upper management. So I am just here to do my job and get paid.